# Create a new commit not including some old

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

So, i have a repository in mercurial as described at the picture below. I need to create a **new commit** but **without changes** that was done by two commits. Lets name these 2 commits as "commit 4" and "commit 16". But I can't just "rewrite the history" and delete these commits.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to "reverse" those changes, or "back out" those changes, meaning you want to undo them, make changes that effectively removes the changes those changesets introduced? In other words, if changeset 4 added something, and changeset 16 modified something, you want your new changeset to remove what 4 added, and modify back to how it was before you committed changeset 16?

Comment: Yes, new changeset should remove that was add in 4 and modify back that was at 16.

Comment: But other than that it should contain everything that is in the top changeset, let's label it changeset 23, did I understand it correctly then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: `backout` the changesets you do not need or want anymore:

```
hg backout -rXXX
```

where XXX is the revision of the changeset you want to see gone. Thus in your case first checkout your last changeset (e.g. 23), then:

```
hg backout -r4
hg backout -r16
```

and your task is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I understand you want to do:

1. Take the topmost (latest) changeset, let's call this changeset 23
2. "Undo" whatever changeset 4 and changeset 16 did on top of this

This gives you:

1. Changeset 23 is still intact, complete with whatever changeset 4 and 16 did
2. Your new changeset(s) would be like 23, except without whatever changeset 4 and 16 did

Here's how to do this, here's the history prior to the operations:

```
     23
     |
     ...
     |
     16
     |
     ...
     |
     4
     |
     ...
```

1. Update to the topmost changeset
2. Create a backout changeset for changeset 4 and commit it, this will be committed on top of changeset 23
3. Create a backount changeset for changeset 16 and commit it, this will be committed on top of changeset 24

Your history should now look like this:

```
     25 (-16)
     |
     24 (-4)
     |
     23
     |
     ...
     |
     16
     |
     ...
     |
     4
     |
     ...
```

Note that:

- Changeset 23 still contains changeset 4 and 16
- Changeset 25 contains changeset 23, but the changes from 4 and 16 have been reversed (backed out)
- If changes in 5 and up rely on changes introduced in changeset 4, and/or changes in 17 and up rely on changes introduced in changeset 16, you will get merge conflicts, you will need to handle these when merging

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it, and let you know if it works.

Comment: While the answer works, it is IMHO far too complicated. Why first update to the changesets? You can simply update to changeset 23 and then backout the unwanted changesets directly without any need to merge

Comment: I was not aware that you could back out a changeset without being *on* that changeset, you're right, far too complicated.